# How to add an extra domain name to Exchange?

Tags: exchange-2003, domain

We would like to be able to send and receive mail using an extra domain name.  We want to be able to tack on extra email addresses (with the new domainname) to our existing AD users.

I've added the DNS entry, I just need to configure Exchange.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Some additional information: I've added the new domain to our default recipient policy, and added the new email address to my user account - i can send mail to myself, but not from my gmail account.  I also cannot send from this new address.

Thanks,

Ashley

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just edit your [recipient policies](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319201) to include the additional addresses.  Here is a step-by-step [guide](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_exchange_2000_2003_to_receive_email_for_other_domains.htm).

Comment: +1 - Congrats on breaking 10K.

Comment: +1 - Recipient policies is what you need and the guide in Petri is an A+.